# Double column figure* with custom single-column margins for text

Tags: floats, two-column, vertical-spacing

I have a single pdf figure included with includegraphics, and already use the trimming and clipping options to crop the source image. It is placed in a double-column document, but I want for this single figure to enable both text-columns to start from a different margin from the figure. In fact, I want the second column to start higher than the first column, with partial overap with the figure.

Current code:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\caption{\label{fig:setup}caption text}
\includegraphics[clip,trim={0.3cm 0cm 1.6cm 0.3cm},width=\linewidth]{fig.pdf}
\end{figure*}
```

Desired (box depicts the included pdf figure):

[image]

Comment: use a single column figure so it overlaps the second column and add a `\vspace*{...}`  in the text at the right point to make a partial gap at the top of the second column.

Comment: 1) Is there any way to do this dynamically, by specifying within the figure environment, instead of hardcoding this in the text?
2) The caption above the figure should remain double-column, does this still hold for the vspace solution?

Comment: yes you can put a `\textwidth` wide minipage in the singlecolumn float so the image and caption can be full width. You could try to make a second (empty other than a vspace) float that floats to the top of the second column rather than use vspace in the main text